# recursive 2 with Cakephp functional

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.x

I need to build a select drop-down list from data from `find()`.

When I perform a recursive find:

```
$parlamentarios = $this->Revocatorio->Parlamentario->find('all', array('recursive' => 2));
```

It returns the following:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Parlamentario' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'postulacion_id' => '4',
        'created' => '2016-01-10 20:29:47',
        'periodo_id' => '1',
        'voto_parlamento' => '4000'
    ),
    'Postulacion' => array(
        'id' => '4',
        'registro_id' => '2',
        'comite_id' => '5',
        'periodo_id' => '1',
        'fecha_elec' => '2016-01-23',
        'created' => '2016-01-03 20:40:18',
        'voto' => '0',
        'Registro' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'cedula' => '',
            'nacionalidad' => '1',
            'nombre' => '',
            'seg_nombre' => '',
            'apellido' => '',
            'seg_apellido' => '',
            'genero' => true,
            'fecha_nac' => '-',
            'lugar_nac' => 'Portuguesa',
            'fecha_reg' => '2015-12-02',
            'direccion' => 'aijhaoihdwaoih',
            'edad' => '21',
            'foto' => '1 LOGO UNERG.jpg',
            'foto_dir' => '2',
            'leer' => true,
            'escribir' => true,
            'discapacidad' => 'ninguna',
            'aptitud' => true,
            'estado_civil' => 'Casado/a',
            'ccregistro_id' => '0',
            'name' => ' - '
        ),
        'Comite' => array(
            'id' => '5',
            'comite' => 'awdawdawdawd'
        ),
        'Periodo' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'periodo' => '2015-2017'
        ),
        'Escrutinio' => array(),
        'Revocatorio' => array()
    ),
    'Periodo' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'periodo' => '2015-2017',
        'Ccregistro' => array(),
        'Escrutinio' => array(),
        'Postulacion' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'registro_id' => '3',
                'comite_id' => '3',
                'periodo_id' => '1',
                'fecha_elec' => '2015-12-24',
                'created' => '2015-12-22 05:42:21',
                'voto' => '200'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'id' => '3',
                'registro_id' => '2',
                'comite_id' => '1',
                'periodo_id' => '1',
                'fecha_elec' => '2016-01-20',
                'created' => '2016-01-03 05:46:46',
                'voto' => '0'
            ),
            (int) 2 => array(
                'id' => '4',
                'registro_id' => '2',
                'comite_id' => '5',
                'periodo_id' => '1',
                'fecha_elec' => '2016-01-23',
                'created' => '2016-01-03 20:40:18',
                'voto' => '0'
            ),
            (int) 3 => array(
                'id' => '5',
                'registro_id' => '3',
                'comite_id' => '9',
                'periodo_id' => '1',
                'fecha_elec' => '2016-01-21',
                'created' => '2016-01-03 20:41:03',
                'voto' => '0'
            ),
            (int) 4 => array(
                'id' => '6',
                'registro_id' => '3',
                'comite_id' => '11',
                'periodo_id' => '1',
                'fecha_elec' => '2016-01-14',
                'created' => '2016-01-03 21:06:27',
                'voto' => '0'
            ),
            (int) 5 => array(
                'id' => '7',
                'registro_id' => '2',
                'comite_id' => '1',
                'periodo_id' => '1',
                'fecha_elec' => '2016-01-22',
                'created' => '2016-01-04 02:38:17',
                'voto' => '0'
            )
        )
    ),
    'Escrutinio' => array(),
    'Revocatorio' => array()
),
```

The relationships are:

```
Revocatorio hasMany Parlamentario
Parlamentario hasMany Postulacion
Postulacion hasMany Registro
```

I need save the `id` of `Parlamentario`, but show  `Postulacion.Registro.name` in add view. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Am I understanding you right? You want to create a [selectbox](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html) with Parlamentario.id => Parlamentario.Postulacion.Registraro.name?

Comment: But there might be multiple Postulacion and Multiple Registro - so there would be for example one Parlamentario.id with 3 names. How should the resulting selectbox look like in your opinion? Can you add an example result you want to achieve in your question?

Comment: one example can be this...in my find() do something like this $parlamentarios = $this->Revocatorio->Parlamentario->find('list', array('recursive' => 2, array('fields' => array('Palarmetario.id', 'Postulacion.Registro.id')); but the field 'Postulacion.Registro.id' show me error on sql

Comment: I meant how the result should look like.

Comment: something like this 
`array(
(int) 'Parlamentario.id => 'Postulacion.Registro.name',
(int) 'Parlamentario.id => 'Postulacion.Registro.name',
(int) 'Parlamentario.id => 'Postulacion.Registro.name',
(int) 'Parlamentario.id => 'Postulacion.Registro.name',
(int) 'Parlamentario.id => 'Postulacion.Registro.name',
(int) 'Parlamentario.id => 'Postulacion.Registro.name', 
)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->Parlamentario->find("list", array(
        "fields"  => array("Parlamentario.id", "Postulacion.Registro.name"),
        "contain" => array("Postulacion.Registro")
       )
     );
```

Peace! xD

Comment: thanks for answer and hi, i see the behavior, but this find it's with the finally to show one select  with this datas.

So the find is with 'list'. how i can use the field "name" on "Parlamentario.Registro" with the field atribute?